# Windows 10 UWP - How to check if Cellular data is enabled?

Tags: windows-10-universal, cellular-network

In Windows 10 UWP, how can I check if cellular data is enabled ?

I don't want to know what type is my current internet connection (NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()), I want to know if the cellular data radio is activated.

I think in Windows 8, we can do it using DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled, is there an equivalent for Windows 10 UWP ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this using NetworkInformation Class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx

```
ConnectionProfile networkProfile= NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (networkProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile)
{
    WwanDataClass connection = networkProfile.WwanConnectionProfileDetails.GetCurrentDataClass();
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this tells if my current internet connection is wwan. But I'd like to know if the cellular data option is enabled on my phone. I could have a Wlan internet connection and cellular data enabled or disabled...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not sure if this will do exactly what you want, but I think you can try calling `MobileBroabandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds` and select the first in range to get your default network account id. Then call `MobileBroadbandAccount.CreateFromNetworkAccountId` on that network account id and try using `MobileBroadbandNetwork.NetworkRegistrationState` on that network. See the MobileBroadbandNetwork documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.mobilebroadbandnetwork)  and the possible fields [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkregistrationstate).</strike>

Here's my example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Current network registration state is: " + MobileBroadbandAccount.CreateFromNetworkAccountId(MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds[0]).CurrentNetwork.NetworkRegistrationState);
```

I think that if your cellular data is disabled the result of this call will be  **Deregistered**. I don't have a windows phone, but this is the case on my Windows desktop with a Mobile Broadband USB stick.

I know it's kinda of a work-around, but I'm not sure of any other way to just check if cellular data is enabled. Hope this helps in some way.

## Edit

I did some more searching and found this similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594833/how-to-detect-airplane-mode-programmatically-in-windows-phone-10).

You should be able to use the answer there to solve your problem.