# How to detect airplane mode programmatically in windows phone 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I want to detect airplane mode in windows phone 10 ( Universal Windows Application ) programmatically. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241148) documentation and `MobileBroadbandRadioState` enum for UWP apps but it's reserved for mobile operators and you can't use it in app you want to upload to Store.

First, you have to edit `Package.appxmanifest` file and add **rescap** namespace

```
<Package
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp wincap rescap">
```

and add new capability

```
<rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity"/>
```

In your project add this code to check airplane mode status

```
var ids = MobileBroadbandAccount.AvailableNetworkAccountIds;
var account = MobileBroadbandAccount.CreateFromNetworkAccountId(ids[0]);

Debug.WriteLine(account.CurrentDeviceInformation.CurrentRadioState);
```